# Singleton Use - How to make Data Available to all Classes?

Tags: java, singleton

I have created a singleton class using the following code:

```
public class Singleton {

 private static Singleton instance = null;
 private Singleton() {
  // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
 }

 public static Singleton getInstance() {
  if(instance == null) {
     instance = new Singleton();
  }
  return instance;
 }
}
```

I now want to make data from my program available to all of my classes using this singleton class (any suggested modifications are more than welcome). How do I proceed to do so?

Comment: Two comments. 1) Classes that need it get a reference to the singleton with `Singleton.getInstance()`; this is the whole point of the singleton pattern to begin with.  2) Don't use Singleton, use dependency injection and let the framework provide the references to shared objects where they are needed.

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't the Singleton have additional attributes for each set of data I want it to hold?

Comment: WIth Singleton, the singleton becomes a massive switchboard containing all sorts of shared data.  It exposes all common data, most of which is NOT used by a specific bit of client code, and grows unwieldy as the system grows.  With DI you would inject the individual objects where they are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now you can initialise your Singleton with data in your constructor, or you can add methods to your Singleton class to get data.

Then you'll just have to import the Singleton class in your other classes and get your instance with getInstance().

If you want to look into a more up to date way of accessing data from multiple classes, you could take a look into dependency injection.

Comment: This answer is "correct" as far as it goes, but should come with the caveat that the Singleton pattern is deprecated in favor of dependency injection, except in very small systems where a DI framework like Spring might be considered excessive.

Comment: I tried to stick to his question, I'm not familiar enough with dependency injection to give a proper alternative. I'll add the suggestion to my answer though, good call!